# Sort on the basis of new added data in solr?

Tags: search, solr

When we are searching on solr we want to get the newer results on the top.

Can anybody please suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The question is not really clear, if you want to order results by date you just have to apply a sort on the needed date field (assuming that you have one):

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents

If you want to boost results that are more 'fresh' than others you can have a look here:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Date_Boosting